# using references to SFRs in gcc inline assembler

Tags: programming, c++, assembly, gcc

I want to write a driver that can use either timer0 or timer2, based on a choice made at compile time.

So I want all references to timer registers to be abstracted, e.g. OCRA for OCR0A/OCR2A, etc.

I could do it with plain macros, like so:

```
#define _CONCAT3(a,b,c)   a##b##c
#define CONCAT3(a,b)   _CONCAT3(a,b,c)

// set timer number globally
#define MY_TIMER 2

// define an alias for each control register
#define OCRA CONCAT3(OCR, MY_TIMER, A)
```

**but** for some reason I don't want to use macros there.

So I came up with this scheme:

```
typedef volatile uint8_t& tRegister;

constexpr volatile uint8_t& timer_register (volatile uint8_t& a, volatile uint8_t& b)
{ return MY_TIMER==0 ? a : b; }

tRegister OCRA = timer_register (OCR0A, OCR2A);
```

It works pretty well for all its awkwardness, *but* when I try to use this definition in an inline assembly directive, I get strange results:

```
asm volatile("lds r24, %0" : : "i"(&OCRA));
```

will get an `error: impossible constraint in 'asm'`

Now this:

```
asm volatile("lds r24, %0" : : "i"(&timer_register (OCR0A , OCR2A )));
```

will compile (and produce `lds r24, 0x00B3` as it should).

By definition a reference to a static variable is a constant address, known at compile time, so I can't see why it can't be used in this context.

So my questions are:

- what is going on there?
- how to alias these registers (without macros) to please the inline assembler?

Answer (score 1):

You could use pointers instead of references. With pointers, you have
the separate notions of “constant pointer” and “pointer to constant”. A
reference is a kind of pointer coated with syntactic sugar. However,
whereas you can have a “constant reference” (equivalent to *pointer to
constant*), I do not know how to declare a “reference with constant
address” (which would be the equivalent of a *constant pointer*). And
this is your issue: the `"i"` constraint in the `asm` statement requires
a constant.

Here is my take with pointers:

```
typedef volatile uint8_t * tRegister;

constexpr tRegister timer_register(tRegister a, tRegister b)
{ return MY_TIMER==0 ? a : b; }

// The `const' below is essential.
const tRegister OCRA = timer_register(&OCR0A, &OCR2A);

asm volatile("lds r24, %0" : : "i"(OCRA));
```

Of course, you then have to change all your `OCRA = ...;` statements
with `*OCRA = ...;`, which is awkward. But note that the avr-libc
defines the SFRs with macros equivalent to

```
#define OCR0A (*address_of_OCR0A)
```

If you want this convenience, you may have to resort to using similar
macros yourself.

Comment: Well thanks, but that's a workaround. I actually did something similar, but limited to the asm directives, so that I could at least use my reference aliases in the C++ code. I guess this fine docrine point about the difference between a reference and a constant pointer is just another small hole in the atrociously convoluted specs of C++ the poor guys who implemented the inline assembler fell into :D.